# Nginx YII rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, yii

I have 3 folders under the document root of the website:

```
/usr/share/nginx/example.com/public_html# ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  73 Jul 17 07:28 app
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  76 Jul 17 07:28 base
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 211 Jul  8 14:32 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  57 Jul 22 11:10 public
```

Content of .htaccess:

```
/usr/share/nginx/example.com/public_html# cat .htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Content of 'public' subdirectory:

```
/usr/share/nginx/example.com/public_html/public# ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   27 Jul 17 07:28 css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  219 Jun 23 10:17 .htaccess
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6860 Jul 17 07:15 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   26 Jul 17 07:15 js
```

And finally content of underlying .htaccess:

```
/usr/share/nginx/example.com/public_html/public# cat .htaccess 
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

As this is based on YII framework, I took [their Nginx sample configuration](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.apache-nginx-config#nginx) and modified it this way:

```
server {
    access_log  /usr/share/nginx/example.com/logs/access.log  main;
    error_log  /usr/share/nginx/example.com/logs/error.log;
    rewrite_log on;

    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/example.com/public_html;

    charset utf-8;

    index  index.php index.html;


    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /public$1 last;
    }
    location /public {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /public/index.php?_url=/$uri;
    }

    location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
        deny  all;
    }

    #avoid processing of calls to unexisting static files by yii
    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

        #let yii catch the calls to unexising PHP files
        set $fsn /index.php;
        if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
            set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        fastcgi_pass   unix://var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;

        #PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED can be omitted, but RFC 3875 specifies them for CGI
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fsn;
    }

    # prevent nginx from serving dotfiles (.htaccess, .svn, .git, etc.)
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

This behaves the way that whatever page I access on the website, every-time only index page is shown.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit 1**

To make the question clearer, what I need to achieve is to rewrite htaccess files above so it works properly in Nginx.

This part is what I came up with:

```
    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /public$1 last;
    }
    location /public {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /public/index.php?_url=/$uri;
    }
```

**Edit 2 - solution**

I replaced this:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /public$1 last;
}
location /public {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /public/index.php?_url=/$uri;
}
```

by this:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/$1 last;
}

location /public {
    rewrite ^/public/(.*)$ /public/index.php?_url=$1;
}
```

I've added a slash sign in the first rewrite and used rewrite instead of try_files in case of second rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /public$1 last;
}
location /public {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /public/index.php?_url=/$uri;
}
```

to this

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/public/(.*)$   /public/index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: So your answer pointed me to the correct solution. I replaced this:

`location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /public$1 last;
}
location /public {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /public/index.php?_url=/$uri;
}`

to this

`location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/$1 last;
}

location /public {
    rewrite ^/public/(.*)$ /public/index.php?_url=$1;
}`

I've added a slash sign in the first rewrite and used rewrite instead of try_files in case of second rule.
Thanks for pointing me to a right direction ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. nginx doesn't use htaccess files;
2. Check input data into your index.php. insert "" into your index.php. if output contain '_url => ....', ngixn  work correctly;

> var_dump($_REQUEST);

3. Also you always can use nginx debug information

> error_log /path/to/log debug;

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this fact and the only reason why I mentioned content of current .htaccess files and highlighted directory structure was to give some insight about what worked in Apache - I should've made myself clearer.
The site completely works in Apache and I'm trying to make it working in Nginx. I've edited the question to reflect this.